# Unity's GetComponent by string (or by some other method being passed from another script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use as few scripts as possible, so I'm instantiating (example:) `Button` with `buttonScript` prefab from `Spawner` with `spawnerScript`. On `Button` being clicked (detected in `buttonScript`) I want a specific function to be called in `spawnerScript` - but without `Spawner` or `spawnerScript` being defined by user in `buttonScript`. They can be injected into this script, but cannot be typed out in script or defined in Unity's editor. How do I do this?

tl;dr - how do I call a function in other script without typing out script's name in GetComponent manually? Injecting target script for GetComponent is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Something like this ? `gameObject.GetComponent("YourScriptAsString") as YourScriptType;`

Comment: If I understand correctly then just get a handle to the script once using GetComponent and set to a variable.  Then just use that variable in future lines of code.

Comment: @Programmer Exactly, except what is "YourScriptType" supposed to represent?

Comment: The name of your script or the class . For example `public class Hello : MonoBehavior {}`. The `Hello` in this case

Comment: @Programmer sure, but I don't have this defined in buttonScript. How do I pass this "Hello" into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a delegate to the Button

```
 public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour{

       void Start(){
             GameObject btn = Instantiate<GameObject>(btnPrefab);
             btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Method);
        }
        void Method(){}
 }
```

EDIT based on comment:

"button contains a very simple script holding only a single GameObject (**assigned at instantiation**)"

So you're passing the GameObject at instantiation. Let's consider in the following example that this target is given from GetTarget() (I dunno how you get it)

```
void Start()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++)
    {
         GameObject btn = Instantiate<GameObject>(btnPrefab);
         GameObject target = GetTarget();
         btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(()=>
         {
             Method(target);
         });
    }
}
void Method(GameObject obj)
{
    Debug.Log(obj.name);
}
```

The concept to grab here is the lambda expression with the arrow. This can be understood as a method with no name that is only used in there (since it has no name you can’t call it elsewhere). That method returns void and has no parameter so it matches the Button listener requirements. In that nameless method you call another method that takes the GameObject target. Here a closure is created so even the Button object does not know about the target, it finds it.

Not so simple at first but you’ll get it.

Comment: This seems to be a relatively good solution for my needs (except I actually need variables from the button, but can probably be worked out). Can I get button's gameobject somehow when this is clicked (assume 100 are spawned, and not kept in lists)? Thumbs up, if I don't get an answer specifically for what I'm asking for I'll pick it as an answer.

Comment: (as in, can I get the gameObject which is clicked and triggered the method, if "btn" is overwritten with time?)

Comment: You should look into lambda methods. Also what data, from where and how to be used?

Comment: I'm making a universal button prefab (that will be used in big lists) where button contains a very simple script holding only a single GameObject (assigned at instantiation). In spawners (and there will be multiple), they are using "for" to spawn many of these buttons, modifying them and "forgetting" them as soon as it's done. I want this same spawner script to be called from button and pass it's target GameObject (from buttonScript, assigned earlier) without the script name of spawner GameObject being defined by user. it can be defined automatically when button is instantiated, not otherwise.

Comment: As in, I'm trying to pass a target script into instantiated GameObject, that will be used in standardized function. On click, I want a value assigned at instantiation to be returned to the script that spawned this specific button - at least that's the effect I'm trying to achieve as simply as possible.

Comment: Even though it's not a direct answer to the initial solution I accepted this because it fits my needs perfectly. What happens to these listeners when it's target (button(s)) gets destroyed? I don't want the script to accumulate thousands of listeners over time.

Comment: The script does not accumulate anything. It takes the button component of the newly created button and assigned its method to it. If the Spawner script is destroyed then your button will get null reference exception (actually it depends on what you do but let's not get there), if you destroy the button, the link from Button to Spawner method is removed and nothing happens. Though it is a good practice to clear or remove the listeners on destroy.

Answer (score 1):

Make your Spawner script static so there is always only one and you can access it with the Class instead of a variable version.

then instead of

GameObject.GetComponent().doMethod();

its

```
Spawner.doMethod();
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that because I intend to spawn other buttons that call other "spawners" (GameObjects with their own scripts).

Comment: If I'm misunderstanding your comment, please say. I'm trying to create universal button into which different target scripts can be passed to be used by same function.

Comment: That probably won't do since he has 100s of buttons and they would all use that static method since they all share it.